# how to use --multifile ARM compilation option with eclipse

Tags: arm, compiler-flags, armcc

I want to compile ARM c project using ARMCC compiler.

`--multifile` is used to perform additional optimizations by compiling across several source files (having one object file output).

example
`armcc -c --multifile test1.c ... testn.c -o test.o` .

my question is how to use this compilation flag with eclipse. I can't just put it  in ARM C Compiler -> miscellaneous like `--inline` for example, because it affects many files in same time